# Как задать url для нового плагина Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет.
Вопрос по `WordPress`: Как задать `URL` созданному плагину? Т.е. создаю свой плагин, он разбивается на пользовательскую и админскую части и я хочу чтобы, скажем, по ссылке `http//my_site.ru/my_plugin.php` выполнялся клиентский код моего плагина, как это можно сделать?
И вообще: я могу без всяких дополнительных манипуляций вызвать свой клиентский код (например `http//my_site.ru/index.php?page=my_plugin`)?
Если да, то какой ссылке?

Comment: URL где и для чего именно?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить свою страницу через хук add_options_page https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus
Там задается и название и функция обработки и еще пару параметров.